# Cassandra streaming

Tags: stream, cassandra

I am using `cassandra version 1.1.4` and for bulk loading data. I am creating `SSTables` and then trying to stream them to the cassandra cluster. I am trying this only on a single node (my own system) and thus have kept replication factor as `1`. But streaming fails every time I try to, and the following error message occurs

```
progress: [/10.66.92.92 0/6 (0)] [total: 0 - 0MB/s (avg: 0MB/s)]Streaming session to /10.66.92.92 failed
Exception in thread "Streaming to /10.66.92.92:1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.unchecked(FBUtilities.java:628)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.receiveReply(FileStreamTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.stream(FileStreamTask.java:181)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.runMayThrow(FileStreamTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
    ... 3 more

progress: [/10.66.92.92 1/6 (16)] [total: 16 - 0MB/s (avg: 0MB/s)]Streaming to the following hosts failed:
[/10.66.92.92]
```

When I close the server and restart it, I can see my tables inserted, but I dont want this. I want streaming to happen successfully and avoid restarting the server again and again. Cassandra folks please help! I am Using a Windows 7 environment

Comment: Could you post your code. Also try the link https://github.com/yukim/cassandra-bulkload-example/

Comment: Also please let me know if you fixed it.